# Tensorflow throw value error when checking input (lstm_1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

model.fit produces exception:

***ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (60752, 29)***

this is the model structure:

```
 train_x, valid_x = arr[:split, :], arr[split:, :]

train_y, valid_y = target[:split], target[split:]


train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], -1)
train_y = train_y.reshape(train_y.shape[0], -1)
valid_x = valid_x.reshape(valid_x.shape[0], -1)
valid_y = valid_y.reshape(valid_y.shape[0], -1)

print(train_x.shape)

input_params = train_x.shape[1]
print(input_params)

model = Sequential()
#start
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(input_params, 1)))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=2))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=2))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=2))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

`

these are the parameters of the model:

```
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 29, 100)           40800     

_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 29, 100)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 29, 100)           80400     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 29, 100)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               80400     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 202       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 3         
=================================================================
Total params: 201,805
Trainable params: 201,805
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Anyone can help me to fix this?

Comment: reshape your input data to match the input of `lstm_1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect your input to be only 1 channel then either

[1] reshape the `x`

```
train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], -1)
train_y = train_y.reshape(train_y.shape[0], -1)
valid_x = valid_x.reshape(valid_x.shape[0], -1)
valid_y = valid_y.reshape(valid_y.shape[0], -1)

train_x = np.expand_dims(train_x, -1)
valid_x = np.expand_dims(valid_x, -1)
```

or [2] add a `Reshape` layer

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Reshape((-1, 1)))
#start
```

should do it.